# Imagelist.from_folder() in Fastai returns different number of classes when re-running the same cell

Tags: pytorch, imagelist, fast-ai

I have been trying to create a databunch using `Imagelist.from_folder()` function in Fastai (in Google Colab) . I have 750 folders(classes). However when I ran `Imagelist.from_folder()` function the first time, it returned 749 number of classes! 1 class less. So I re-ran the code cell again, this time it returned 748 number of classes and again running third time it returned 746! I checked the number of sub-folders in the main folder again by using '`glob`' in python and there were 750 folders(the exact). So why is the Fastai function returning different number of classes (folders) everytime i run it. I am attaching the screenshot below for your reference.

After executing the cell for the first time:

```
Number of classes : 749
```

After executing the cell for the second time:

```
Number of classes : 748
```

After executing the cell for the third time:

```
Number of classes : 746
```

How can this be possible when I have exact 750 folders (as *classes*)!

I suspect is this due to using ***Imagelist.from_folder()*** and maybe do I need to use ***ImageDataBunch.from_folder()*** ?? Or is there any issue with google colab trying to fetch the data from Gdrive

[image: Number of classes: 749]

[image: Number of classes: 748]

[image: Number of classes: 746]

Comment: For future posts (and perhaps worth considering for this one) please copy-paste the relevant part of your code, inputs, and outputs in text format rather than in images. It is quite annoying to try to decipher what is happening in your code with images like that.

Comment: Ya sorry I know that might be quite annoying, but if I just kept text, I am afraid you probably won't understand what I meant to say. Sorry for the inconvenience!